# what is the difference between Fixed Frames (top left of rviz window)?

Tags: openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch

3.Quick start

Set the Fixed Frame (top left of rviz window) to /camera_depth_optical_frame.

There are /camera_depth_frame, /camera_depth_optical_frame, /camera_link,

/camera_rgb_frame and /camera_rgb_optical_frame.

what is the difference between /camera_depth_frame, /camera_depth_optical_frame,

/camera_link, /camera_rgb_frame and /camera_rgb_optical_frame.?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36638/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-frames-(top-left-of-rviz-window)?/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `*optical` frames use a special camera image orientation, unlike normal transform frames. See [REP-0103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#coordinate-frame-conventions).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3